# measuring total swap with SNMP when swap is larger than 4TB

Tags: snmp, swap

We have a system with more than 4TB of swap space. I want to measure it's memory with SNMP (because I'm using MRTG to graph it). SNMP is reporting negative numbers for memTotalSwap. I suspect that this is because it's being reported with a 32-bit number:

```
$ snmpwalk -v 2c -c ******** localhost Memory
UCD-SNMP-MIB::memIndex.0 = INTEGER: 0
UCD-SNMP-MIB::memErrorName.0 = STRING: swap
UCD-SNMP-MIB::memTotalSwap.0 = INTEGER: -205520900 kB
UCD-SNMP-MIB::memAvailSwap.0 = INTEGER: -205520900 kB
UCD-SNMP-MIB::memTotalReal.0 = INTEGER: 784103952 kB
UCD-SNMP-MIB::memAvailReal.0 = INTEGER: 730528620 kB
UCD-SNMP-MIB::memTotalFree.0 = INTEGER: 525007720 kB
UCD-SNMP-MIB::memMinimumSwap.0 = INTEGER: 16000 kB
UCD-SNMP-MIB::memShared.0 = INTEGER: 0 kB
UCD-SNMP-MIB::memBuffer.0 = INTEGER: 412400 kB
UCD-SNMP-MIB::memCached.0 = INTEGER: 21600812 kB
UCD-SNMP-MIB::memSwapError.0 = INTEGER: noError(0)
UCD-SNMP-MIB::memSwapErrorMsg.0 = STRING:
```

Is there any easy workaround?

Comment: 4TB of _swap_? Congratulations, you're probably going to win the award for the wildest thing I've seen all week.

Comment: i agree never seen that within 17 years of work, whats that for a System?

Comment: We are working with a big model. Amazon has machines which have 8TB of RAM but they are not available for use with EMR. Our working set of dat is probably in the neighborhood of 30-50TB but we have a set of machines in the cluster.